# What Happens when I use all of my CPU resources?

Tags: linux, cpu, failure

I've been trying to convert some video with `ffmpeg` and realized that this is taking ~97% of my cpu when I check with `top`.  What exactly happens when I use 100% of processor?  How does it fail?  Can I get an alert or log when that happens or is the OS gone at that point?

Comment: @JYelton I already flagged it to be migrated to superuser for the moderators. Unfortunately, myself or OP cannot move it to superuser even if he knows about superuser. I'll comment about SU anyways as you suggest.

Comment: @tarabyte This question of yours is believed to be related to a CPU involved with encoding or decoding video streams. This type of question is better suited for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) rather than [http://electronics.stackexchange.com](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: 100% CPU use means you're (finally) getting your money's worth performance. Most of the time your system has a too expensive CPU because it is only used for waiting and idle'ing. Other than that, I agree this question is a better fit for superuser as it is not about electronics design and more about computer use.

Comment: A busy CPU is a happy CPU.

Comment: @jippie: If slightly reworded the question could be suitable for electronics.  Some embedded systems have certain tasks that *need* to get done with a certain degree of timeliness, and if they would take more than 100% CPU some or all of them won't get done.  Embedded systems programmers often have to examine what's going on and ensure that the CPU will be able to keep up with critical tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that your PC or OS won't fail, it can perfectly well handle a situation like that. Probably all fans will run full speed to cool the system, but the system is designed for a situation like that.

## Not CPU but memory should be your worry.

Only thing you want to watch is `swap use` which you don't want near 100%. If that happens you apparantly have too little RAM (and/or swap space) and Linux will start killing random processes to prevent the system from crashing. (Actually it does a slightly educated guess when selecting processes to kill and in this case your `ffmpeg` process would have high likeliness te be killed.

```
top - 11:53:33 up 5 days, 14:00,  3 users,  load average: 1.08, 0.84, 0.79
Tasks: 246 total,   2 running, 243 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  6.4 us,  1.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 91.3 id,  0.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8074916 total,  7511956 used,   562960 free,   476140 buffers
KiB Swap:  8388604 total,  1521824 used,  6866780 free,  1223412 cached
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In any case your system will not be physically damaged by high CPU or memory load.